# Bluetooth “out of band” (OOB) pairing on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need to securely paired a bluetooth device to an iOS device, 
I know that in Bluetooth 4.0 and 4.1 there is three way to do the pairing : Just Works, Passkey Entry and Out Of Band (OOB).

We need to use the highest security paring protocol, which it found to be the Out Of Band (OOB) method.

I know that apple used the OOB method for pairing the apple watch to an iPhone, at least they say so in the [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) (at the end of the page 22).

So I'm wondering is there any API from apple that I can use for pairing my device with the OBB method, or maybe you can suggest me any other secure method.

Thank you so much for your help, it's highly appreciated !

Comment: In the version of May 2019, Apple Watches are on page 37 of the Security Guide now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only available bonding (pairing) method in Core Bluetooth is passkey entry.

The Apple Watch uses an OOB technique involving an image captured by the phone's camera with a fallback to passkey, but this is not available to other apps.

If your device has a display and can generate a random passkey then this technique is much the same as OOB in terms of security.  If your device doesn't have a display then the security depends on how the passkey is shared (e.g. fixed passkey such as 0000 for all devices, not very secure.  Random passkey for each device on a sticker is more secure)

Comment: A random passkey isn't the same as OOB on BLE 4.1 and earlier - passkey used symmetric encryption so it is [vulnerable to passive eavesdroppers](https://lacklustre.net/projects/crackle/). (It was a deliberate design flaw; nothing was 'cracked'. Also it isn't fair to say that BLE 4.1 encryption is worthless - the attacker has to be present during pairing to break it.)